# Does the concept of eternal damnation exist in Judaism?

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, hashkafah-philosophy, reward-punishment, gehinnom

Does the concept of *eternal* damnation exist in Judaism? This is not about some temporary state of judgement like is referred to on Rosh HaShanah 17a by the expression לדורי דורות, but a permanent condition that does not end.

If it does exist, what are the sources for this? Is the first mention in the written Torah or did it appear and develop later?

Comment: is your question about the "eternal" part or the "damnation" (as opposed to something else) part?

Comment: According to the definition found in most dictionaries, it means condemnation  to eternal punishment (Onesh as in S'char v'Onesh) in hell (Gehinom).

Comment: But is your question about the nature of the Onesh as compared to other theological constructs of "damnation" or simply about the "eternal" part?

Comment: I am not limiting the question to the type or nature of Onesh. But it would seem to be relevant to any answer. The eternal element is in my view essential to the question since the concept of eternal reward in Olam HaBa is a generally accepted idea.

Comment: Note that the feeling of shame for having done wrong would persist even if any other punishment has been completed and done with.

Comment: @DoubleAA You still are not dealing with the fact that the question you say is a duplicate is actually just a poor translation by the OP of the phrase לדורי דורות. That question is only asking what the length of time is for that expression. "Eternal damnation", whatever that means, does not appear in the question you cite or the one poor answer that appears there. Please remove this question from the duplicate list.

Comment: That question asks if the claim that "some sins which warrant eternal gehinom" is to be taken literally or not. That is the same question as "Does the concept of eternal damnation exist in Judaism?" If there is some way they are different, just edit to clarify. Neither post is very good as it is, being all of 1-2 sentences long each.

Comment: @DoubleAA Last time I checked, "damnation" translates as קללה. I'm leaving those who want to answer with the job of defining it. If you want to make a case for saying that Gehinnom means eternal damnation, make an answer. But please stop trying to suppress other voices and opinions.

Comment: Leaving it to the answerers to define your question is what's known as "Unclear What You Are Asking". Always write your question clearly, noting precisely what you are seeking and whatever relevant background and motivation is needed to understand the issues.

Comment: @DoubleAA My question is clear and precise. The phrase can be understood many different ways depending on who is reading. Your view and understanding, DoubleAA, is not the only one. Part of the benefit of this site, at least in theory, is that we are all benefitted from hearing viewpoints other than our own. Moderation privileges are not for suppression and censoring.

Comment: @YaacovDeane please remember to edit clarifications into the question and, in particular, how this question is different from the one it's marked as a duplicate of.  If you edit it, it will automatically go to the reopen review queue.

Comment: How do you know that RH 17 is referring to something temporary? The other question thinks it refers to something eternal. Why should we trust you over them?

Comment: Because לדורי דורות is repeating the teaching of Moshe Rabbeinu from BaMidbar 14:18. Dorot is 2. Dorei Dorot is 2 times 2 for 4. Until the fourth generation.

Comment: Your trust should be in G-d and in Moshe, His servant.

Comment: RASH"I appears to accept the peshat of Yeshayahu 66:24 וְיָצְאוּ֨ וְרָא֔וּ בְּפִגְרֵי֙ הָֽאֲנָשִׁ֔ים הַפֹּֽשְׁעִ֖ים בִּ֑י כִּ֣י תֽוֹלַעְתָּ֞ם לֹ֣א תָמ֗וּת וְאִשָּׁם֙ לֹ֣א תִכְבֶּ֔ה וְהָי֥וּ דֵֽרָא֖וֹן לְכָל־בָּשָֽׂר: and Daniel 12:2 וְרַבִּ֕ים מִיְּשֵׁנֵ֥י אַדְמַת־עָפָ֖ר יָקִ֑יצוּ אֵלֶּה לְחַיֵּ֣י עוֹלָ֔ם וְאֵ֥לֶּה לַֽחֲרָפ֖וֹת לְדִרְא֥וֹן עוֹלָֽם:, in which the concept of eternal damnation or eternal punishment or "The dead will come to life" (as RASH"I comments) is written.